# Save the pointer value in parse.com with iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, pointers, parse-platform

I want to add an id to a pointer field in Parse.  I have 2 classes `categories` and `Ads`.  In the `categories` class, the `objectId` is a String that I am using to get all the fields of the `Ads` class. In the `Ads` class, the `cat` field is a pointer to `categories`. Now I add the `cat` id with another column that is a String. The String field is added but the pointer column 'cat' is not added.

Here is the code:

```
let ex = "s8HiwfvKtQ"
let posts = PFObject(className: "Ads")
posts.setObject(ex, forKey: "cat")
```

or alternatively

```
posts["cat"] = ex 
posts.saveInBackground()
```

I tried the above code and found other solutions but still cannot save the `cat` field.

Below is a screenshot of the `categories` and `Ads` classes:
[image: Categoris class]
[image: Ads class]

Error in console is:

> invalid type for key cat, expected *categories, but got string (Code: 111, Version: 1.10.0)

Answer (score 2):

It is throwing error because `cat` is a `category object` and you are setting object as `String` you must set an object for `cat` row.

you must do something like:

```
 let ex = PFObject(className: "categories")
        ex.objectId = "s8HiwfvKtQ"

        let posts = PFObject(className: "Ads")
        posts.setObject(ex, forKey: "cat")

        posts.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }else{
                print(success)
            }
        }
```

Comment: I try above code but again error in console is :"object not found for update (Code: 101, Version: 1.10.0)"

Comment: have you checked objectId. Does `s8HiwfvKtQ` exist in categories

Comment: yes ,now i change the objectId that is exit in categoories then error in console is:"Attempted to change an objectId to one that's already known to the OfflineStore."

Comment: `object id` must be an `id of category` not `Ads` i think u are using an id which exist in `Ads`

Comment: ya but the objectId of category column and cat of Ads column both are same.ObjectId of category is use in Ads class as pointer field